# Discover which (if any) route will match a given URL from within Controller in ASP.NET MVC2 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my master page I have a placeholder where a Html.RenderPartial() will render a collection of (bread)crumbs which are effectively a list of links I build up using action, controller names and RouteValueDictionary's.

I have an action that is called from multiple places to view a short-list and so when building the list of breadcrumbs for this actions view to display. Ideally I'd like to use Request.UrlReferer as the penultimate crumb.

Before unconditionally using this URL I want to check that it will actually match at least 1 route so I can be sure if the user clicks it they will get a view from my app and if they don't I will simply use the home page instead.

Any suggestions how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx